# Getting the width and height of an image if its max-width property is set to some value

Tags: html, css, image, browser, aspect-ratio

I have a `img` I dont know width and height of the image.So I have to fit this image inside a static width and height area,after searching for solution i got `max-width` property manage these kind of issue. 
I used max-width property for my img tag.It works great.But I confused that, how the browser calculates based on this single property ,even it does not set this width as image width.

I know how to calculate the height of the image if i know the width.

**Example**

```
original width = 100px;
original height=200px;
default width = 50px;
default height = original height/original width*default width;
default height = 200/100*50 = 100px;
```

**Result**

```
default width = 50px; //default static width i set
default height = 100px; //dynamic based on default width and aspect ratio
```

**MyQuestion**
To find height it should have static width, but the browser(i am using mozilla), how it calculate both width and height if its max-width attribute.So does it calculates as i did?

Please help me to find this..

```html
<img src="http://ad009cdnb.archdaily.net/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/1258661197-009-f0-reception.jpg" style="max-width:200px"/>
```

Comment: Is there any reason preventing the use of JS for this task? The image element itself can tell you how large it is - both its display size and its actual size. See here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_img_naturalwidth.asp

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not entirely sure about the end result your looking for but I worked this up and it reports the original size as well as the modified size after adjusting only the width.

```html
<html>
<body>

    <img id="image1">
 <hr>
 <div id="result"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

function getImgSize(img,imgelem) {
 result = document.getElementById("result");
 width = img.width;
 height = img.height;

 document.getElementById(imgelem).width = (width*2);

 newwidth = document.getElementById(imgelem).width;
 newheight = document.getElementById(imgelem).height;

 result.innerHTML = "<br>original width: "+width+"<br>original height: "+height;
 result.innerHTML += "<br>new width: "+newwidth+"<br>new height: "+newheight;
}

img1 = new Image();
img1.src="images/example_image.gif";
document.getElementById("image1").src = img1.src;
img1.onload = function() {getImgSize(img1,"image1");};

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please understand myquestion its only in frontend, there is no  php involved, i can get the image width and height through `var im=new Image();im.src=url;im.onload=function(){ console.log(im.width+":"+im.height);};`